# loading data in datagridview through database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am having a problem loading data in datagridview. I am loading data from database on form_load in combobox and then loading data in datagridview on selecting value from combobox with respect to that value. The problem is that data is not displaying in datagridview.
Note:
i am using a class "Repo" for establishing connection.`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qu = "select month from emp_salary";
        ds = rp.getdata(qu);
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["0"];
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "month";
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qu = "select * from emp_salary where month='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        ds = rp.getdata(qu);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["0"].DefaultView;
    }    `
```

Comment: Don't you need to `Bind` the datasource to the gridview?

Comment: You need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries. What you have here is vulnerable to sql injection. You do not want to ever build up a string and execute it like that.

Comment: I think that ds.Tables["0"] should be ds.Tables[0] and also start using parameterized queries

Comment: I am building code for the desktop app not for web app